# Error when importing the processor library

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `processor` library but whenever I do `import processor`, it gives me this error:

```
File c:\users\souregi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\hy\macros.py:67 in import
    parse_tree = pattern.parse(args)

  File c:\users\souregi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\funcparserlib\parser.py:221 in parse
    (tree, _) = self.run(tokens, State(0, 0, None))

  File c:\users\souregi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\funcparserlib\parser.py:383 in _shift
    (v, s2) = self.run(tokens, s)

  File c:\users\souregi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\funcparserlib\parser.py:306 in _add
    (v2, s3) = other.run(tokens, s2)

  File c:\users\souregi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\funcparserlib\parser.py:534 in finished
    raise NoParseError("got unexpected token", s2)

NoParseError: got unexpected token: hy.models.List([
  hy.models.Expression([
    hy.models.Symbol('.'),
    hy.models.Symbol('collections'),
    hy.models.Symbol('abc')]),
  hy.models.List([
    hy.models.Symbol('Iterable')])]), expected: end of input
```

steps to reproduce: `pip install processor` and then `import processor`. This error happens with python 3.8 and 3.9

Answer (score 0):

A small workaround is to install hy==0.19.0

```
pip install hy==0.19.0 --force
```